# Android Keyboard Widget

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, mobile-development

I would like to know if my idea is possible and to get some insights into how I could achieve that.

My idea: implement my app widget into the Android Keyboard (OnePlus 7) like in the following pictures:

[Android Keyboard Widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvY3R.png)

[Widgets View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BiWD.png)

Cheers!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Android keyboard.  They keyboard is an app.  Not every OEM ships with the same keyboard app.  Even of those that do, these apps are, by and large, not customizable.  And that's ignoring the fact that the user can download entirely different keyboard apps from the play store.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. Would it be possible to tackle my idea somehow differently in a similar manner? I am trying to focus on simplicity for the end user and implementation of the actual App "Widget".